# What is the best way to return multiple tags from a Rails Helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I want to create a hidden field and create a link in one helper and then output both to my erb.

```
<%= my_cool_helper "something", form %>
```

Should out put the results of

```
link_to "something", a_path
form.hidden_field "something".tableize, :value => "something"
```

What would the definition of the helper look like? The details of what link_to and the form.hidden_field don't really matter. What matters is, how do I return the output from two different calls.

Comment: remember that [since Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) you need to mark strings as `html_safe` to avoid XSS attacks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

Remember that the existing rails helpers like `link_to`, etc, just output strings. You can concatenate the strings together and return that (which is what I do most of the time, if things are simple).

EG:

```
link_to( "something", something_path ) +  #NOTE THE PLUS FOR STRING CONCAT
  form.hidden_field('something'.tableize, :value=>'something')
```

If you're doing things which are more complicated, you could just put that code in a partial, and have your helper call `render :partial`.

If you're doing more complicated stuff than even that, then you may want to look at errtheblog's [block_to_partial](http://errtheblog.com/posts/11-block-to-partial) helper, which is pretty cool

Comment: Nice and simple answer! Plus FTW!

Answer (score 11):

So far the best I have come up with is:

```
def my_cool_helper(name, form)
  out = capture { link_to name, a_path }
  out << capture { form.hidden_field name.tableize, value => 'something' }
end
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

### Using `safe_join`.

I typically prefer just concatenating with `+`, as shown in [Orion Edwards's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112211/293280), but here's another option I recently discovered.

```
safe_join( [
  link_to( "something", something_path ),
  form.hidden_field( "something".tableize, value: "something" )
] )
```

It has the advantage of explicitly listing all of the elements and the joining of those elements.

I find that with long elements, the `+` symbol can get lost at the end of the line. Additionally, if you're concatenating more than a few elements, I find listing them in an Array like this to be more obvious to the next reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to buffer other output which apart from string then you can use `concat` instead of `+`.
see this - http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/

Answer (score 1):

```rb
def output_siblings
  div1 = tag.div 'some content'
  div2 = tag.div 'other content'

  div1 + div2
end
```

just simplifying some other answers in here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
def format_paragraphs(text)
  text.split(/\r?\n/).sum do |paragraph|
    tag.p(paragraph)
  end
end
```